# A C++ "in" operator without cruft?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to emulate Python's `in` operator in C++ (11), using immedate values as you can in Python.  Such as:

```
if x in (1, 2, 3): ...
```

In C++11, it seems I'm close to being able to do this:

```
if (IsIn(x, { 1, 2, 3 }))
    {
    }


template<typename Val, Container cont>
bool IsIn(Val const &val, Container const &cont)
    {
    return boost::find(cont, val) != cont.end();
    }
```

But (in g++-4.8) I get:

> error: no matching function for call to 'IsIn(MyType&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

I know I could do this, but that's a lot of cruft:

```
if (IsIn(x, std::initializer_list<MyType>{1, 2, 3 })) ...
```

What's the elegant solution?

**UPDATE:**  I hadn't thought enough about compile-time vs. run-time, and I still can't decide if there's a clear winner.  My `IsIn(x, {})` surely has more run-time loop overhead and copies the initializer_list values, but also works with any container.  The `... == any_of(...` mechanism would surely compile to tighter code and doesn't copy, but only works with immediates (which was my original example) and not containers, and the sytax (to me) seems a little less straight-forward.

Since it's kind of a tie, I'm awarding it to the contributor in appreciation.

Thanks to everyone for the discussion!

Comment: Another way you might do a similar thing: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bcf0c0b56b47ce3

Comment: You may look at [named-operators-in-c++](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23179/named-operators-in-c) or https://github.com/klmr/named-operator for *named-operator* to be able to use `if (x <in> {1, 2, 3})` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologise for the shameless plug, but I think it solves the OP's problem.

You may use [this library](https://github.com/giacomodrago/smart_conditions):

```
#include "smart_conditions.hpp"
using namespace smart_conditions;

// ...

if (x == any_of (1, 2, 3))
{
    // ...
}
```

It supports other relational operators, it **works at compile time** (`constexpr`) if all the operands are known at compile time, and it makes **no copies**. Plus, **it works with mixed types**, meaning that `if (std::string("x") == any_of ("x", "y"))` compiles fine.

Comment: This really does not add anything compared to the other answers.

Comment: Well, if you look at the source code, I think it does. The idea is not to use an initializer_list, nor a container, nor any sort of iterator but to exploit tuples and variadic templates. I am really sorry it sounds like self-promotion. And even if you don't inspect the code, it does simply and exactly what the OP asks with little or no "cruft." I believe you should reconsider ;)

Comment: The OP clearly *wants* initializer lists and he *wants* containers. Not using them makes it de facto pretty useless for him.

Comment: He/she says "using immediate values" and this sounds so *not* "wants containers" to me. The OP used initializer lists as an attempt to find a solution, not to express a requirement. The new answer by davidhigh - which I will upvote - pretty much does what my `any_of` does, except it makes copies, and that unfortunately makes my solution still better (I say unfortunately because it sounds like self-promotion). The OP could throw my solution into his/her code and it would *just* work for *exactly* what she/he wants, plus a number of desirable features (e.g. compile-time evaluation).

Comment: I can't decide if I want containers or not. I used initializer_list because I was enamored by them.  But a more-immediate list like this seems better, especially if it compiles to a single compare per item w/o copying (and doesn't slaughter the compile time). On the down-side, it would be nice to use the same mechanism for containers built at run-time.  And the `... == any_of ...` syntax is seems a little less straight-forward.  (No points off for the self-promotion!)

Comment: @JimB: thanks for the feedback, I understand. Well, that won't work with containers built at runtime of course, so you've got a point, and I didn't understand this requirement. As for the syntax, it mimics natural language, i.e. you read `if x is equal to any of ...`. Writing a wrapper would be piece of cake, or you can read my source and write an `in` that works the same way. Your `in` can probably help passing through a temporary tuple.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was right under my nose...

```
template<typename Val>
bool IsIn(Val val, std::initializer_list<Val> const &cont)
    {
    return boost::find(cont, val) != cont.end(); // include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
    // Or if you don't want boost, include <algorithm>
    // return std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), val) != cont.end();
    }
```

Comment: As a more general solution, I would create both overloads, so you can use a hand-crafted initializer list or a container filled at run-time.

Comment: `std::find` is not working in place of `boost::find` with g++ -std=c++14  -O2 -Wall -pedantic . I checked with clang also

Comment: You just want to know if `Val` is present in `cont` so simply do `return std::any_of( begin(cont), end(cont), Val)`.

Comment: It should be noted that initializer_list binds by value, so if used with class types this will copy them all

Comment: @black: That won't work, `std::any_of` takes a _predicate_ not a _value_.

Comment: @T.C. if glvalues are put in the search list in this example then they are all copied to form the initializer list. (rvalues may be moved)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Blastfurnace has a good point - use `boost::any_of_equal`. which does take a predicate.

Comment: Consider my answer as a solution that works with mixed types and even at  compile time.

Comment: Is there a way to do away with the copy and still have an elegant solution? Just don't sweat it for simple types?

Comment: @Steephen: did you notice the extra parameter (that boost::range removes)? `std::find` sure ought to work.

Answer (score 2):

Another little idea:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
struct in_impl
{
    in_impl(T const& t, Args const& ... args) : val({t, args ...}) {}

    std::array<T, sizeof ...(Args) + 1> val;
};


template<typename T, typename ... Args>
bool operator==(T const& t, in_impl<T, Args ...> const& in)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(in.val), std::end(in.val), t) != std::end(in.val);
}


template<typename T, typename ... Args>
auto in(T const& t, Args const& ... args)
{
    return in_impl<T, Args ...>(t, args ...);
}
```

This can be used as

```
int main()
{
    if(1 == in(1,2,3) )
    {
        std::cout<<"1 is in"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5050753066c930ec)

A bit more care could be taken in getting the leading type `T`, but the idea should become clear.

Comment: I think this approach could also be made `constexpr`.

Comment: I think it *should*. And if you use tuples plus perfect forwarding, you can work with mixed types and avoid copies.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases, one where you can call `container.find(value)` and another where you call `std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), value)`:

```
template<typename IteratorType, typename Type>
bool
contains ( IteratorType first, IteratorType last, Type const& value )
{
    return std::find ( first, last, value ) != last;
}


template <template <typename, typename ...> class ContainerType, typename KeyType, typename... Types>
bool
contains_key
    ( ContainerType <KeyType, Types ...> const& container
    , KeyType const& key
    )
{
    return container.find ( key ) != container.end ( );
}
```